# Regular expression: replace google analytics code

Tags: php, regex

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");

document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
try

{

    var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("xx-xxxxxxxx-x");

    pageTracker._setDomainName(".com");

    pageTracker._trackPageview();

} catch (err) { }

</script>

<script src='bla.com/gaAddons.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
```

I have this old google analytic code in multiple files. I need to replace the entire code above with `<script src='external_file.js' type='text/javascript'></script>`.

I am using php and this is my regular expression: `/<script.*>.*<script src='.+gaAddons.js' type='.+'><\/script>/` It is not working and there is an issue.

Comment: Is the Google Analytics code the same every time?

Comment: If you decide to go the parse & `xpath` route, this would be your xpath of nodes to delete: `//script[contains(string(),"gaJsHost")] || //script[contains(string(),"_getTracker")] || //script[@src="bla.com/gaAddons.js"]`, but I tire of advocating this superior method to regex....

Comment: @Wrikken this might fail if the document is not well-formed... (this is the only reason regex would win here) :)

Comment: It might, the chances are however slimmer, and a lot of parsers can recover from minor errors in form of the loaded document, so the problem with the original document would have to be very serious.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the `s` flag to your regex, the [DOTALL](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) modifier enables `.` capturing also newlines:

```
/<script.*>.*<script src='.+gaAddons.js' type='.+'><\/script>/s
```

You should probably better use a HTML parser instead of a regex in this case, though.

Comment: I realize that there are some javascript on top of the posted code. I modified it a bit, but it is not working /<script.*>\/s+var gaJsHost.+<script src='.+gaAddons.js' type='.+'><\/script>/s

Comment: @kenpeter hmmm that's why it's probably not the most safe way to use a regex in your case ... You should better replace the nodes with DOM or some HTML parser ... Because it would be quite difficult with regex to be generic enough and safe enough at the same time (ie. removing the good things and only the good things in every cases) ... Actually with your example, `/<script.*>.*</script>/s` does the job, but it actually would match the largest pair of `script` tags and with everything betwixt the between (of course without caring about any nested structures, being regexes and only regexes)